# Converting DVD to still images

Tags: video, time-lapse

I have a DVD. Its basically an hour long video that is just a collection of photos that rotate to a new photo every 5 seconds or so. What I am looking for is a program that will convert the entire movie into a collection of jpegs or TIF files. If it converted every frame of the video into an image, that is fine, but preferably I'd like it to detect when the image changes and then capture the image.

I've seen many programs, like VLC that will capture a single image, but I'm looking for something that is more automated. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -r 0.25 -i video.mpg -f image2 %05d.png
```

`ffmpeg` invoke the program

`-r 0.25`  force the frame rate of

`-i video.mpg`  your input file

`-f image2 %05d.png`  force the format of  the output file

From the [ffmpeg site](http://ffmpeg.org/about.html):

> FFmpeg is the leading multimedia framework, able to decode, encode,
>   transcode, mux, demux, stream, filter and play pretty much anything
>   that humans and machines have created. It supports the most obscure
>   ancient formats up to the cutting edge. No matter if they were
>   designed by some standards committee, the community or a corporation.
>   It contains libavcodec, libavutil, libavformat, libavdevice,
>   libswscale and libswresample which can be used by applications. As
>   well as ffmpeg, ffserver, ffplay and ffprobe which can be used by end
>   users for transcoding, streaming and playing

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more information, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many programs that will do the job for you. Most media converter programs are capable of doing it. Personally I use Adobe Media Encoder, but if you don't want to spend any money, a free one will work just as well.

I found this one: [Video-AVI to GIF/JPG converter](http://download.cnet.com/Video-AVI-to-GIF-JPEG-Converter/3000-2194_4-10379741.html)
It says that you can specify how many frames per second you want. This means that if it changes picture exactly every 5 seconds, you can set it to capture every 120. frame. You take the fps and multiply it by the number of seconds. 24x5 = 120. Thus, it will capture a frame every 5th second. (Be aware that it can be for example 30 fps if you're using the NTSC standard.)

It should do exactly the job you need to be done!

Leave me a comment if it works for you or not!

EDIT: Do you have the movie in a .AVI file? If you don't, tell me, and I'll explain how you can rip it. (You probably know it already.)

Comment: in this context, I interpret 120fps to mean 120 frame captures per second. In the case of 5 second intervals, you want 1/120 fps (1 screen cap for every 120 frames). Note that NTSC DVD is not exactly 24fps, so there will be a time differential which increases as with playback time.

Comment: @horatio Yes, you're probably right.